# Автозагрузка в Zend Framework

Tags: framework, zend-framework

Прочитал, что использовать `fallback`-режим автозагрузки - очень плохо.
Прочитал много про автозагрузку, но запутался. Как мне подключать мой класс автоматически?
Класс `Articles` объявлен в файле `application/models/Articles.php`.
В файле `application/controllers/ArticlesController.php` используется класс `Articles` (без ручного подключения файла). После того, как я убрал `fallback`-режим, он, конечно, перестал находить этот класс.
Как мне можно добиться его автозагрузки?

P.S.: в `bootstrap.php`, если что, есть вот такая строка:

```
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

Comment: Кто подскажет?)

Comment: А, я вроде понял.
Мне надо зарегистрировать мой префикс:

     $autoloader->registerNamespace('lol');
При этом, мне этот префикс (в примере - lol) добавить в названия и классов, и их файлов, к примеру, вместо файла `Articles.php` с классом `Articles` сделать `lolArticles.php` с классом `lolArticles`.
Вот теперь работает (до этого, когда не получалось, я делал похоже, но добавлял префикс не к имени файла и класса одновременно).
Так работает. Это правильно?